# Problem in setting path in yml for Spring Cloud Gateway using regex

Tags: regex, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

The below configuration works as expected

`- id: test-service`
`uri: http://localhost:8080/`
`predicates:`
`- Path=/ap1/test/**,/api2/test/**,/api3/test/**`

I am trying to use the OR condition(as shown below) for the above paths. Is there a way we can achieve it using regex and not code/redirect

```
- Path=/(api1|api2|api3)/test/**
```

Comment: The syntax is not regex. If the first one works, why not use it?

Comment: Yes it is not regex, but is there a way if we can have or in place? Also in case if I have to add api4, api5 then in that case I need to make another entry, so I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: we don't support that. `/api*/test/**` would work in the case you mentioned.